# How to register callback with Windows handle?

Tags: c, windows, hwnd

I am using a C library that uses windows callbacks to do unsolicited messaging. I can't figure out how to register a callback with a windows handle.

Here is the prototype of the function I'm attempting to use:

```
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_unsolicstart( unsigned short FlibHndl, short number, HWND hWnd, unsigned long msgno, short chkalive, short *bill );
```

It is asking for a windows handle `HWND hWnd` but I can't figure out how to register a callback with this handle.

Here is the windows callback function I want to get called by the library:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {}
```

How can I tie this all together?

Comment: The technique is called "subclassing a window", you'll get good hits from Google when you query that phrase.